# Post to friends wall with IOS SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, image, facebook-graph-api, posting

I am able to post images on users wall with the following :-

```
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
    {
        FBSession.activeSession  = appDelegate.session;            
        [FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:img 
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   [self showAlert:@"eCard Posted" result:result error:error];
                               }];

    }
```

Now the requirement is to pick friends from friend picker class and post the image on the selected friends wall/timeline.

I have integrated the Friends picker class as follows:-

```
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
    {
         FBSession.activeSession  = appDelegate.session; 
        if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
            // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
            self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
            self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
            self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
        }

        [self.friendPickerController loadData];
        [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];            
        [self presentModalViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];


   }
```

Now in the delegate method :-

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender {

// we pick up the users from the selection, and create a string that we use to update the text view
// at the bottom of the display; note that self.selection is a property inherited from our base class
//UIImage *img = self.image;
    FBSession.activeSession = appDelegate.session;

for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) {   

    FBSession.activeSession  = appDelegate.session; 
    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
    {            
        NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       // [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"me" forKey:@"name"]; 
       // [postVariablesDictionary setObject:self.image forKey:@"picture"];
        [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"Sample Text" forKey:@"message"];
         NSLog(@"%@",user.id);
        [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",user.id] graphObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:postVariablesDictionary] completionHandler:nil];


     }    
    else 
    {
        if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
            // Create a new, logged out session.
            appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        }            
        // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                         FBSessionState status, 
                                                         NSError *error) {
        }];
    } 

}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

The above Delegate method is always leads to a Error code =5 facebook sdk error  . What API should be called to make the above image get posted in the selected friends wall.

Please Help me.......

Answer (score 1):

Finally i am able to post images on the friends wall.

**The Delegate Method modified as follows :--**

```
- (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender {

// we pick up the users from the selection, and create a string that we use to update the text view
// at the bottom of the display; note that self.selection is a property inherited from our base class
//UIImage *img = self.image;
FBSession.activeSession = appDelegate.session;
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
{            
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"user_photos",@"", nil]
                                   allowLoginUI:NO
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {
                                      NSLog(@"error");
                                  } else {
                                      [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];
                                  }
                              }];


    for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) {   


        if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
        {    

            FBSession.activeSession  = appDelegate.session; 
            NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
             [postVariablesDictionary setObject:self.image forKey:@"source"]; 
            // [postVariablesDictionary setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image)  forKey:@"source"];
            [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"my image" forKey:@"message"];
            NSLog(@"%@",user.id);
            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",user.id] parameters:postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                [self showAlert:@"eCard Posted" result:result error:error];
            }];
        }    
        else 
        {
            if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
                // Create a new, logged out session.
                appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            }            
            // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
            [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                             FBSessionState status, 
                                                             NSError *error) {
            }];
        } 

    }

}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Regard and thanks....

Comment: Yes.In Facebook IOS SDK 3.0.